# Does $I[2^n,2^{n+1}]$ converges weakly to $0$? or weak-*?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Two questions one after another.

**Q1**:Does $I[2^n,2^{n+1}]\in L^p$ ($1<p<\infty$) converges weakly to $0$? (Consider $g\in L^q$ $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$)

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{2^n}^{2^{n+1}}gd\mu\le|\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{2^n}^{2^{n+1}}gd\mu|+|\int_{-\infty}^1gd\mu|=|\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{2^n}^{2^{n+1}}gd\mu+\int_{-\infty}^1gd\mu|\le\int|g|d\mu\le\int|g|\mathbb{1}d\mu\le(\int|g|^qd\mu)^{\frac{1}{q}}\le\infty$

(the second last inequality by Holder)

So $\int_{2^n}^{2^{n+1}}gd\mu\rightarrow0$

So $I[2^n,2^{n+1}]\in L^p$ converges weakly to $0$.

**Q2**:Does $I[2^n,2^{n+1}]$ converges weakly-* to $0$ for $L^\infty=(L^1(\mu))^*$?

Yes because above argument still applies to weak convergence thus implies weak-* convergence

Are my justification correct?

Comment: What space are you looking at? What are your assumptions on $\mu$? What is $I[a,b]$? It appears to be the linear functional $g\mapsto\int_a^bgd\mu$ on $L^q$, but this is not at all clear. It then seems you've identified the bounded functional $I[a,b]$ with an element of $L^p$, but again, this is not at all clear. Please be more precise with your question.

Comment: @Jason: $I[a,b]$ is the characteristic function of the interval $[a,b]$ I believe.  Then I assume we're taking about Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$, but agree ZHU could clarify.  Elements of L^p determine bounded functionals on L^q, $g\mapsto \int gf\,d\mu$, which for characteristic functions of intervals gives what you mention.

Comment: @JonasMeyer thanks that what I mean

Answer (score 1):

In your solution to Q1, I do not know where the inequalities are from, or how you tried Hölder, and the conclusion is incorrect, as you can see from the example $g(x) =1/x$ on $[1,\infty)$, which is in $L^q$ for all $q>1$, and which demonstrates that your sequence does not converge weakly to $0$ in $L^p$, for all $p$ with $1<p<\infty$.  You get $\int_{2^n}^{2^{n+1}}g(x)\,d\mu=\ln(2)$ for all $n$.

For Q2: The "above argument" doesn't apply but the idea of using that sum would work this time because $g$ will be $L^1$ so the series will converge, hence its terms go to $0$.

Comment: @ZHU: My answer still applies.  Your edits make more explicit why your argument doesn't work, as you have more incorrect inequalities.  Mainly: It is not true that $\int |g| \leq \|g\|_q$, as an $L^q$ function need not even be in $L^1$, and my answer gives you an explicit example of this which also show the conclusion is false.  Note that the constant function $1$ is not in $L^p$, and the application of Hölder doesn't make sense.